# Expectation values in QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, measurements, vacuum, probability

What is the meaning of different expectation values in QFT?

For instance:

$$\langle 0|{\cal O}(0)|q,s\rangle$$

or

$$\langle 0|{\cal O}(0)|0\rangle$$

with ${\cal O}$ being some operator and $|q,s\rangle$ some single particle state with the written quantum numbers.

For instance, in Srednicki's textbook I mostly see expectation values of the second kind, i.e. 
$\langle 0|{\cal O}(something)|0\rangle$. How come?

Answer (score 6):

Expectation values in QFT mean the same thing as they do in quantum mechanics.  It's just that certain of these guys, the so-called vacuum expectation values (VEVs) $\langle 0|\rm{operator}|0\rangle$ turn out to be especially useful and important in QFT.

In particular, the correlation functions (aka Green's functions) of the QFT, which for the theory of a single, real scalar field $\phi$ read
\begin{align}
  G(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \langle 0|\mathrm T[\phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)]|0\rangle
\end{align}
are  vevs of time-ordered products of field operators.  These objects are fundamental.  You can, for example, use them to compute scattering amplitudes.

Comment: What about $\langle 0|{\cal O}(x)|q,s\rangle$? Why is it not occuring more often in elementary QFT? I mostly see it i articles.

Comment: @LoveLearning Well I'm not sure how to answer why something is *not* used very much in general.  I could, for example, retort "well if I want to compute a scattering amplitude, for example, I wouldn't need such a thing," the point being that is just depends on the context.

Comment: OK I appreciate you effort on the VEV, but could you give an example of an expectation value of the first kind and explain it in words? This would then answer my question. Thanks man.

Comment: @LoveLearning Sure thing.  Let's consider a single, non-interacting real scalar field, then you can show (see e.g. Peskin and Schroeder p. 24) that $\langle 0|\phi(0,\mathbf x)|\mathbf p\rangle = e^{i\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf x}$ which can be interpreted as the position space wavefunction of a single particle state with momentum $\mathbf p$.  Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @LoveLearning : Don't forget that $|q,s\rangle = a^\dagger(q,s)|0\rangle$, so you have $\langle 0|{\cal O}(0)|q,s\rangle = \langle 0|{\cal O}(0) a^\dagger(q,s)|0\rangle$

Comment: Exactly Trimok. So the reason why I haven't come across (in Srednicki for instance) what you wrote on the lhs is that he writes it as you did on the rhs.

Comment: @Trimok That's a great point.  I was under the impression though that when Love Learning writes $\langle 0|\mathcal O(x)|q,s\rangle$, the operator $\mathcal O(x)$ is local in spacetime position, but $\mathcal O(0)a^\dagger(q,s)$ cannot be written as a local function of spacetime position.